# How to loop through a JSON like this with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, loops

I want to loop through a JSON like this using javascript.

```
{
    persons: [
      Person {
        name: 'Herbert',
        age: 70
      },
      Person {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 67
      }
    ]
  }
```

My first approach was something like this, but this is not working somehow :(

```
  personArray.forEach((person) => {
    console.log(person.name);
  });
```

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON. Maybe you meant `Person: {`? Also what is personArray? Should we assume it's the array in the JSON object with key `person`?

Comment: is it an array like `[{name:'',age:''},{name:'',age:''}...]`  . if so `yourmainobj.persons.forEach...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not have forEach, you need to do like this:

```js
let personArray = {
    persons: [
    {
        name: 'Herbert',
        age: 70
    },
    {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 67
    }
  ]
}
Object.keys(personArray.persons).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(personArray.persons[key].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json looks invalid. If I understood you correctly, you can do the following:

```
let json = '{"persons":[{"name":"Herbert","age":70},{"name":"Peter","age":67}]}'
let personArray = JSON.parse(json)

personArray.persons.forEach((person) => {
  console.log(person.name);
});
```

or, if it is a real javascript object, do the following:

```
let personArray = {
    persons: [
      {
        name: 'Herbert',
        age: 70
      },
      {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 67
      }
    ]
}



personArray.persons.forEach((person) => {
  console.log(person.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to get name:

```
let personArray = {
    persons: [
      {
        name: 'Herbert',
        age: 70
      },
      {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 67
      }
    ]
}

personArray.persons.map(ele => ele.name) // ['Herbert', 'Peter']
```